# Does it make sense to have a class without constructor?

Tags: c++, class

I am wondering whether it makes sense to have a class without constructor if the derived classes have one. If not, is there a way of doing what I want differently?

My case is the following:
I want the users to only use the derived classes, but those have data members and methods in common.

EDIT: as default constructors exist for classes, it means that the user can always create an instance of Instrument directly, then how can I do what I want?

```
class instrument{
    public:
        double get_price();
        std::string get_udl();

    private:
        double m_price;
        std::string m_udl;

};

class stock : public instrument{
    public:
        double get_dividend();

    private:
        double m_dividend;
};

class option : public instrument{
    public:
        double get_strike();
    private:
        double m_strike;
};
```

Comment: `instrument` has an implicitly-declared default constructor. Were you unaware of this?

Comment: Nop I did not know that, so I cannot prevent users of creating an instance of instrument directly? Is there a way of doing what I want differently then?

Comment: How do you envisage `stock` setting values for the private members of `instrument` ?

Comment: By adding a method to compute the price or at initilization within constructor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want the users to only use the derived classes, but those have data members and methods in common

Have your default (or any other) c'tor, but declare it with `protected` access. Now only derived classes may invoke it. Effectively making it usable only when inherited.

```
class instrument{
    public:
        double get_price();
        std::string get_udl();

    protected:
        instrument() = default;

    private:
        double m_price;
        std::string m_udl;

};
```

This also avoids the overhead associated with making a class abstract. If you don't need polymorphism, you shouldn't use it just to make a class usable only as a base class.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your last thought about abstract class and polymorphism? It’s actually possible using polymorphism with your solution.

Comment: @Germán - The last sentence isn't to say one cannot make `instrument` abstract. It's to say that one shouldn't make it abstract *just* so it cannot be instantiated on its own. Polymorphism brings cost. And I don't think this simple use case warrants it.

Comment: I agree with you about the cost and using it only when it’s necessary. And I clearly prefer your solution over the abstract class one. But I understand from your comment that abstract class brings more overhead than this solution. And that is what I don’t see.

Comment: @Germán - An abstract class means run time polymorphism support must be added (recall that a `vptr` and `vtable` are only created when the first virtual function is decalred). The cost I'm speaking of is in object size.

Comment: I see now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have thought of Abstract class ?

> An abstract class is a class that is declared abstract—it may or may not include abstract methods. Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but they can be subclassed.

Isn't this what you are looking for ?

Comment: I believe this is the answer and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756893/how-to-implement-interfaces-in-c) is a post with an example of implementation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that quote is Java documentation. C++ doesn't have an abstract keyword.

Comment: @Zebrafish Good catch, maybe the answer should be edited with just a loose definition of the concept.

Comment: You can make a class abstract by using the following syntax for any member methods C++:

`virtual void foobar(void) = 0;`

But note that this will force you to implement this function in every single class deriving from your abstract base class.

Comment: (downvote) This is cut and pasted from Java documentation.

Comment: Good catch , I have studied Java . But I checked similar things exist in C++ So I posted. You have C++ definition Please edit my message.

Answer (score -1):

When there's no default constructor defined, the compiler will automatically generate one for you, doing nothing for members of basic types and calls the default constructor for members of struct/class types.

So the conclusion is, it makes no sense to have a class without **any** constructor because whenever you define an instance of that class you have to call **at least one** (more may be called with deligate construction).

Comment: Only if there's no user-declared constructor (default or otherwise) will the compiler generate a default constructor for you.

Answer (score -2):

Yes! Definitely it make sense. Because when user create the `instance` of `derived` `class`, first of all `parent` class's `constructor` will be called from within the `derived` `class` `constructor`. Even without you explicitly call it. And `parent` class's `default` `constructor` will be called even if you didn't create one. By default

```
public constructor with no parameter is present in every class
if it has no overridden constructor.
```

And yes all the public members of parent class will be present in `derived class` after creating `derived class instance`.

Comment: You contradict yourself: you have no constructors, but you call it from derived class?

Comment: I didn't contradict. What i'm trying to tell you if you don't write any of the constructor of a class. There will be a public default constructor always available, that the compiler write itself in the .class file.

Comment: And that would be called on the time of execution.

Comment: Did you seriously just go around all the items here and downvote?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm trying to tell something.