# How to instantiate an abstract class without using new and delete?

Tags: c++

Consider following code,

```
class Interface
{
public:
    Interface(){}
    virtual ~Interface(){}
    virtual void method1() = 0; 
                                  
    virtual void method2() = 0;
};

class Concrete : public Interface
{
private:
    int myMember;

public:
    Concrete(){}
    ~Concrete(){}
    void method1();
    void method2();
};

void Concrete::method1()
{
    // Your implementation
}

void Concrete::method2()
{
    // Your implementation
}

int main(void)
{
    Interface *f = new Concrete();

    f->method1();
    f->method2();

    delete f;

    return 0;
}
```

The [author](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9756896/14659574) used `Interface *f = new Concrete();` to instantiate an abstract class in the main function and later he used `delete f;` but the issue with `new` and `delete` is that I don't like them. Is there are an alternative way to instantiate this class?

Comment: `Concrete f = Concrete();`?

Comment: @jamesdlin What's point of an abstract class if you instantiate derived class directly?

Comment: The point of an abstract class is to declare an interface.

Comment: You don't like `new` and `delete`, but how about `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_unique` to avoid manually deleting?

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin Quite sexier, I forget about them

Comment: @jamesdlin I knew what's an abstract class is but your code doesn't use polymorphism since you instantiate derived class directly.

Comment: @jamesdlin But it could be made as polymorphism if a function take abstract class as arg.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a pointer or reference to the object for polymorphism to work, but you can create that object in whatever way you want.

```
Concrete c;

c.method1(); // no polymorphism, using concrete directly
c.method2();

Interface* f = &c;

f->method1(); // polymorphism through Interface pointer
f->method2();

Interface& f2 = c;

f2.method1(); // polymorphism through reference
f2.method2();
```

Another way to avoid manual `new` and `delete` is to use a smart pointers.

```
#include <memory>

std::unique_ptr<Interface> upf = std::make_unique<Concrete>();

upf->method1();
upf->method2();
```

Comment: StefanKssmr suggested  an another way, `Concrete c;
 Interface& f = c;`. Mind to add that one too?

Comment: @jeffbRTC It's already mentioned in the top paragraph, but I can add the code example too.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?

```
Concrete c;
Interface* f = &c;
```

Comment: that looks good. Can't we get rid from the pointer all together?

Comment: @jeffbRTC You can also have a reference ```Interface& f = c;``` if you don't like pointers (as for pointers, the cast to ```Interface&``` is implicit).

Comment: @StefanKssmr Way better.

Comment: Construction like this ``` virtual void method1() = 0; 
``` means that YOU (the developer) disable to others to instantiate this class (and compiler helps you). You can use something like this ``` virtual void method1(); 
``` without =0. And you will enable others to instantiate this class.

Comment: @Evgeny Yeah, I used a wrong title for what I want to do. Feel free to edit :)  I still don't know what's the right title is.