# In c++ is there any Events/delegates/interfaces/notifications! anything?

Tags: c++, callback, signals-slots

Say i have these classes 
ViewA and ViewB

In objective C using the delegate pattern I could do

```
@protocol ViewBDelegate{

- (void) doSomething();
}
```

then in ViewB interface:

```
id<ViewBDelegate> delegate;
```

then in ViewA implementation i set the delegate:

```
viewB.delegate = self;
```

and now I can call in doSomething from viewB onto any that unknown type delegate.

```
[delegate doSomething];
```

"C++ How to Program" has been the worse read an can't find simple examples that demonstrates basic design patterns.

What i'm looking for in C++ is:

- **events** ActionScript and java
- or delegates or NSNotifications in Objective C

anything that allows class A, Class B and Class C to know that ClassX 
didSomething()!!!

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I were you, I wouldn't use function pointers to accomplish this task. Leave this option to the gurus ;)

In Boost, there is a beautiful library called [signals](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/signals.html). It makes your life easier! This is an example of usage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/signal.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

struct A
{   void A_action() { cout << "A::A_action();" << endl; }   };
struct B
{   void B_action() { cout << "B::B_action();" << endl; }   };
struct C
{   void C_action() { cout << "C::C_action();" << endl; }   };
struct X
{
    // Put all the functions you want to notify!
    signal<void()> list_of_actions;
    void do_something()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello I am X!" << endl;
        list_of_actions(); // send notifications to all functions in the list!
    }
};
int main()
{
    X x;
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;
    x.list_of_actions.connect(bind(&A::A_action, a));
    x.list_of_actions.connect(bind(&B::B_action, b));
    x.list_of_actions.connect(bind(&C::C_action, c));
    x.do_something();
}
```

This will print:

```
Hello I am X!
A::A_action();
B::B_action();
C::C_action();
```

Here is how it works.

First, you declare the place that holds the delegates:

```
signal<void()> list_of_actions;
```

Then, you "connect" it to what ever group of functions/functors/callable things you want to call.

```
x.list_of_actions.connect(bind(&A::A_action, a));
x.list_of_actions.connect(bind(&B::B_action, b));
x.list_of_actions.connect(bind(&C::C_action, c));
```

Note, that I have used `bind`. So, that the type of functions in the list_of_actions is the same, but we can connect it to different type of classes. So:

```
bind(&A::A_action, a)
```

This thing, produces a callable thing, of type `void ()` as we declared the type of `list_of actions` earlier. Of course, you specify the instance you want to apply this member function on in the second parameter..

If you are doing multi-threaded stuff, then use its sister [signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/signals2.html).

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks Arak for taking the time and adding the example. that concludes my search. Brilliant!

Answer (score 5):

> anything that allows class A, Class B
>   and Class C to know that ClassX
>   didSomething()!!!

Probably you are looking for [signals & slots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signals_and_slots), which has multiple implementations:

- [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/signals.html)
- [Qt](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/signalsandslots.html)

I'm sure there are more, but these are the most significant of which I'm aware.

Answer (score 2):

There are no delegates/events/etc.

You can simulate interfaces using pure virtual function, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318064/how-do-you-declare-an-interface-in-c) for a similar question.

And there are the [function pointers](http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html)...

So basically the answer to you question is no, there are none of that in C++ (don't know about the latest standard), but there are substitutes and workarounds..

Comment: thanks I will check out the  interface implementation that should do.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I like [The Impossibly Fast C++ Delegates](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/ImpossiblyFastCppDelegate.aspx) by Sergey Ryazanov. Very neat and easy to use implementation, claimed to be faster than `Boost::function`.

You can find events implemented there, too. I don't use them, however. I implemented my own event handling using .NET style (sender, args).

Comment: Also worth looking at is [Lightweight Generic C++ Callbacks (or, Yet Another Delegate Implementation)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/136799/Lightweight-Generic-C-Callbacks-or-Yet-Another-Del).

Answer (score 1):

Neither the C++ language, nor its associated Standard Library, either have delegates or events. There are of course many libraries that implement such things, or you can implement them yourself.

Comment: thanks Neil. I'm really finding it difficult learning the language, I I realized how spoiling can Objective C and python be!

Comment: @Bach When learning any language, it's important not to try to carry over memes from other languages you know. C++ is really nothing like Python - I can't speak about Objective C. And note that you CAN do delegation in C++ - it's just not part of the language.

Comment: I agree Neil although i can't help it, as I know exactly what I want to do, and I look at how it's done in other languages I've worked with, so I naturally try to find the equivalent in C++. All part of discovering and learning I suppose. Will check out all the suggestions here. Stackoverflow has beaten any book I've read about any language, informative and full of professionals. thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

All i know there is a type of method called **call-back** method(In fact, **function pointer**).

Delegation? It's just a kind of wrapped call-back method, and, looks advanced

Comment: thanks rhapsodyn. I guess i took advanced for granted. nothing's elegant about C++ coming from objective C. anyway thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

> "C++ How to Program" has been the worse read an can't find simple examples that demonstrates basic design patterns

I think that [the original Design Patterns book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns_(book)) includes examples of how to implement each pattern using C++.