# passing this from constructor to other constructor yields undefined reference on linking

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I am trying to compile code with the following structure under codeblocks:

```
class a : public cppcms::application (has virtual members) {
 public:
   a() : b_inst(this) {}
   ...
   b b_inst;

}

class b {
  public:
    b(a* ptr) : a_ptr(ptr) {}
  private:
    a* a_ptr;
  ...
}
```

I am trying to put this together with codeblocks/g++ and get the following error message (at the linking stage):

> undefined reference to `vtable for b (In function b: ...)

I tried pulling of the same thing with a reference, same result. I tried to change a::b_inst to a pointer and creating an instance of b with new in the constructor (codepart), same result.
What is the right way to do this?

By the way, if I do not add the pointer passing on construction, the code works, so i think it is not resolved by the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334269/undefined-reference-to-vtable-for-classname)

Comment: Have you got the declaration in the right order in your actual code? As written, this won't even compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> undefined reference to `vtable for b (In function b: ...)

That means probably you haven't implemented all of `b`'s virtual methods. gcc emits the vtable when the first one is defined AFAIK.

That means it has nothing to do with the implementation of your constructor.

Comment: bedtime for me,
thanks alot, this is right, i forgot that i added more than the constructor, and was fixated at the constructor, since the linker pointed there