# C++ Undefined Reference to vtable and inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, vtable

File A.h

```
#ifndef A_H_
#define A_H_

class A {
public:
    virtual ~A();
    virtual void doWork();
};

#endif
```

File Child.h

```
#ifndef CHILD_H_
#define CHILD_H_

#include "A.h"

class Child: public A {
private:
    int x,y;
public:
    Child();
    ~Child();
    void doWork();
};
#endif
```

And Child.cpp

```
#include "Child.h"

Child::Child(){
    x = 5;
}

Child::~Child(){...}

void Child::doWork(){...};
```

The compiler says that there is a undefined reference to vtable for `A`.
I have tried lots of different things and yet none have worked.

My objective is for class `A` to be an Interface, and to seperate implementation code from headers.

Comment: You must define every non-pure virtual function that you declare. You don't need to define a non-virtual function that you declare but don't use.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

**Why the error & how to resolve it?**

You need to provide **[definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration)** for all virtual functions in `class A`.      Only pure virtual functions are allowed to have no definitions.

i.e: In `class A` both the methods:

```
virtual ~A();
virtual void doWork();
```

should be defined(should have a body)

e.g.:

**A.cpp**

```
void A::doWork()
{
}
A::~A()
{
}
```

---

**Caveat:**
If you want your `class A` to act as an interface(a.k.a **[Abstract class](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Classes/Abstract_Classes)** in C++) then you should make the method pure virtual.

```
virtual void doWork() = 0;
```

---

**Good Read:**

[What does it mean that the "virtual table" is an unresolved external?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#link-errs-missing-vtable)
[When building C++, the linker says my constructors, destructors or virtual tables are undefined.](http://gcc.gnu.org/faq.html#vtables)

Comment: @user1227351: Updated the answer to explain better.Read the links for further explanation.

Comment: Having virtual ~A(); virtual void doWork() = 0; still gives vtable error =/. But without the destructor it works fine. However without it, if i do something like: A *a = new Child(); delete a; obviously it will not call Child::~Child(). Is there a workaround?

Comment: The solution is to place A::~A(){} in Child.cpp

Comment: With C++11, you can use "default" keyword to let the compiler do the job. ex: virtual doSomething() = default;

Answer (score 6):

> My objective is for A to be an Interface, and to seperate implementation code from headers.

In that case, make the member function as pure virtual in class A.

```
class A {
  // ...
  virtual void doWork() = 0;
};
```

Comment: That removes the error if I also remove the destructor. In that case if i do:

    A a = new Child();
    delete a;

what destructor would it call?

Comment: Destruction is always in reverse order of construction. In this case, class `A` destructor must be virtual which enforces `Child` destructor called first followed by `A` destructor. If the `A` class destructor is not virtual then the behavior is undefined.

Comment: It will call the child's destructor as you have made the parent class destructor virtual. After that, the parent class's destructor.

Comment: Having both the destructor and the pure virtual doWork(), in A, leads to a vtable error. How can i define a virtual destructor so that: A *a = new Child(); delete a; leads to a call to Child::~Child()?

Comment: The solution is to place A::~A(){} in Child.cpp

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to delete any "*.gch" files if none of the other responses help you.