# Vtable ran away

Tags: c++, eclipse

```
class MedicineRepository
{
public:
    virtual Medicine* findById(int medId) ;
    virtual Vector<Medicine*> getAll() ;
    virtual int getNrMeds() ;
    virtual void addMed(Medicine s) ;
    virtual void removeMed(int medId) ;
    virtual ~MedicineRepository() ;
};
```

`undefined reference to vtable for MedicineRepository'` is the error I get in this class.I'm inheriting this class in another module and looks like this in the header:

```
class MedRepo : public MedicineRepository{
public: ~MedRepo();
...
};
```

and in the cpp it's defined as :

```
MedRepo::~MedRepo()
{}
```

I don't understand it and I've already looked for something usefull in [Undefined reference to vtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065154/undefined-reference-to-vtable)

Comment: Did you implement all of the functions listed in the .h file?  Sometimes this error arises because you forgot to implement one of them.

Comment: yes,I just checked and they're all there

Comment: Are you using `std::vector` or another vector implementation?

Comment: Do you really want to return a copy of a `Vector`?  Usually, large objects (containers) should be passed by reference, constant reference or use a *visitor design pattern*.

Comment: Why do you have a destructor in the base class without matching constructor, copy constructor and assignment operator?  Search the web for "c++ rule of three".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews If he didn't _define_ the destructor (though it should at least have been, with an empty body), why should he have to ?

Comment: `Vector` is a self made container.I've deleted the declaration of the destructor from all the files and the error is now for the last virtual function and for the first in the inherited class

Comment: This seems small enough to make a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org). Include dummy implementations as needed. Something isn't right in what you have, vs. what you're showing here.

Comment: Like what?Do I need to show more code?

Comment: Apparently the problem was a declaration `MedRepo re;` in another module

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you've posted enough of the error output for anyone to meaningfully determine what the problem is - are you getting it in every file that includes the header, or are you getting it on a specific line of code? In which file? Did you implement the body for ~MedicineRepository?

I would suggest you take a copy of the code, remove as much functionality from the implementations as possible, strip it down to the minimum set of definitions that still generates the error, and then if that doesn't help you solve it, post that.

Comment: Good point, but I think this is more appropriate to put as a comment instead of an answer

Comment: I wasn't getting the option to add comments to questions :)