# Undefined Reference to 'vtable' for derived class and deconstructor of that

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, destructor, definition

I think something is wrong with the deconstructor  but have no idea. In fact, I don't understand the usage of deconstructor.
The code is like this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
public:
explicit A(int x);
virtual ~A()=default;
protected:
int a;
void function1(int X);
};

class B:public A
{
public:
explicit B(int x);
~B();
private:
int c;
};

void A::function1(int X){
  std::cout << "function1 " << X<< endl;
}

A::A(int x):a(0)
{
std::cout << "A " << x+a<< endl;
}

B::B(int x):A(x),c(3)
{
  std::cout << "B " << x+c<< endl;
}

int main()
{
B b1(1);
return 0;
}
```

It shows

/home/qiuyilin/projects/inheritance/main.cpp:36: undefined reference to `vtable for B'
CMakeFiles/inheritance.dir/main.cpp.o: In function`main':
/home/qiuyilin/projects/inheritance/main.cpp:43: undefined reference to `B::~B()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @ser11669150 You did not define the destructor ~B()

Comment: Specifically https://stackoverflow.com/a/15113814/ is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As the error text says

> undefined reference to `B::~B()

you did not define the destructor `~B()`. It is only declared in the class definition of `B` but not defined.

You could write for example

```
~B() = default;
```