# How to create my own library in Arduino with LiquidCrystal?

Tags: c++, arduino, lcd

I am trying to rewrite the LiquidCrystal library as MyLiquidCrystal and so far I have this error: cpp:25: undefined reference to `vtable for MyLiquidCrystal'. I found on the Internet that the library needs to have a destructor and that's what causes this error, but the official library doesn't have an explicit destructor. What can I do to solve this error?
Here is my cpp code: https://pastebin.com/q8Ew8mUp
Here is my h code: https://pastebin.com/Gq23Pixq
And here is the simple code I am running in Arduino:

```
#include <MyLiquidCrystal.h>


MyLiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 10, 5, 4, 3, 2);

void setup()
{
  lcd.begin(16,1);
  lcd.print("hello, world!");
}

void loop() {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not define `virtual size_t write(uint8_t);`

LyquidCrystal does.

Refer to [Undefined reference to vtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065154/undefined-reference-to-vtable)

Comment: thanks a lot, it solved the issue!