# Overloading member function of base class with other derived classes C++

Tags: c++

How can I fix this code? The error that I'm getting is "undefined reference to 'vtable for base' "
The doSomething function should be pure if possible.

**Example:**

```
class A{
};
class A_A : public A{
};
class A_B : public A{
};
class A_C : public A{
};
/////////////////////////////////////
class base{
    public:
        virtual void doSomething(A* );
        //virtual void doSomething(A* ) = 0;  //or...
};

class derived : public base{
    public:
         void doSomething(A_A* );
         void doSomething(A_B* );
         void doSomething(A_C* );
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined reference to vtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065154/undefined-reference-to-vtable)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does an overridden function in the derived class hide other overloads of the base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628768/why-does-an-overridden-function-in-the-derived-class-hide-other-overloads-of-the)

Comment: Are you dead set on having the function in `base`? Either a `template` function, or simple function overloading in `derived` might be a better option.

Answer (score 1):

By adding the `=0` at the back you are forcing the derived class to override the function. This solves the issue:

```
class base{
    public:
        virtual void doSomething(A*a) = 0;
};

class derived : public base{
    public:
    // you can pass any derived class of A to this function
    // mark as override suggested by Omid CompSCI for clarity
    void doSomething(A*a) override { }
};
```

I hope that this helps. Also you shouldn't create 3 different versions of doSomething for each of the derived classes of A because this defeats the purpose of having all those classes inherit from A.

Also consider using smart pointers because they will handle memory dealocation for you. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one/106614#106614) question. This is how I would approach this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>
class A
{
public:
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

class A1: public A
{
public:
    void print() override {std::cout << "A1" << std::endl;}
};

class A2: public A
{
public:
    void print() override {std::cout << "A2" << std::endl;}
};

class A3: public A
{
public:
    void print() override {std::cout << "A3" << std::endl;}
};

class base
{
public:
    virtual void action(std::shared_ptr<A>) = 0;
};

class derived: public base
{
public:
    // this way you can have a generic function which will handle each one of the derived classes of A.
    void action(std::shared_ptr<A> a) override { a->print(); }
};
```

Comment: The declaration in class derived should be void doSomething(A* a) override; This helps a lot when reading the code and making sure we are overriding the function we need.

Comment: I want to overload the doSomething function with the three different subclasses of A. That means that I need three different functions that do different things based on the argument and are derived from the virtual function of the based class.

Comment: Oh I see, in that case what you can do is just include the other 3 functions right under the doSomething(A*); As long as you have that one function overloaded then it will work just fine. Based on the way that it has been structured.

Comment: @Stelios I updated my answer with a suggested alternative solution. I hope that it helps you.