# Undefined Reference to vTable for constructor and destructor

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I have a virtual base class, called AbstractHeap. AbstractHeap has a virtual function, "comp". It also has a (non-virtual) constructor and destructor that should be used by all derived classes, which are implemented.

AbstractHeap is inherited by MinHeap. It implements "comp". It also has a constructor, which just calls the base constructor.

Finally, Main.cpp just creates an instance of MinHeap.

When I compile the program, it gives me this error:

```
$ rm *.o && make
g++ -std=c++11 -c -g AbstractHeap.cpp
g++ -std=c++11 -c -g Main.cpp
g++ -std=c++11 -g -Wall Main.o AbstractHeap.o -o Main
Main.o: In function `MinHeap::MinHeap(int, int)':
/mnt/c/dev/Data_Structures/Lab7/MinHeap.h:8: undefined reference to `vtable for MinHeap'
/mnt/c/dev/Data_Structures/Lab7/MinHeap.h:8: undefined reference to `vtable for MinHeap'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'Main' failed
make: *** [Main] Error 1
owen@MatrixSword:/mnt/c/dev/Data_Structures/Lab7$ rm *.o && make
g++ -std=c++11 -c -g AbstractHeap.cpp
g++ -std=c++11 -c -g Main.cpp
g++ -std=c++11 -g -Wall Main.o AbstractHeap.o -o Main
Main.o: In function `MinHeap::MinHeap(int, int)':
MinHeap.h:8: undefined reference to `vtable for MinHeap'
MinHeap.h:8: undefined reference to `vtable for MinHeap'
Main.o: In function `MinHeap::~MinHeap()':
MinHeap.h:5: undefined reference to `vtable for MinHeap'
MinHeap.h:5: undefined reference to `vtable for MinHeap'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'Main' failed
make: *** [Main] Error 1
```

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065154/undefined-reference-to-vtable) highly upvoted question, but it seems that the problem and solution involved QT, which I am not using.

Here's the code.

AbstractHeap.h

```
#ifndef ABSTRACT_HEAP_H
#define ABSTRACT_HEAP_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Item
{
    int key = -1;
    string data = "";
};

class AbstractHeap
{
    private:
        int k; //A k-heap.
        int size;
        Item* A; //The array.

    public:
        AbstractHeap(int k, int size);
        ~AbstractHeap();

        //Comparison operator. Can be interpretted as c comp b. So, if you want a <, comp is a<b. If the result is true, a has a higher priority than b.
        virtual bool comp(int a, int b) = 0;
};

#endif
```

AbstractHeap.cpp

```
#include "AbstractHeap.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

AbstractHeap::AbstractHeap(int _k, int _size)
{
    size = _size;
    k = _k;
    A = new Item[size];
}

AbstractHeap::~AbstractHeap()
{
    delete [] A;
}
```

MinHeap.h

```
#ifndef MIN_HEAP_H
#define MIN_HEAP
#include "AbstractHeap.h"

class MinHeap : virtual public AbstractHeap
{
    public:
        MinHeap(int k, int size) : AbstractHeap{k, size} {};
        bool comp(int a, int b);
};

#endif
```

MinHeap.cpp

```
#include "MinHeap.h"

bool MinHeap::comp(int a, int b)
{
    return a < b;
}
```

Finally, here's my Makefile, in the unlikely event it is a result of poor Makefile writing.

```
Main: AbstractHeap.o Main.o 
    g++ -std=c++11 -g -Wall Main.o AbstractHeap.o -o Main

Main.o: Main.cpp
    g++ -std=c++11 -c -g Main.cpp

AbstractHeap.o: AbstractHeap.cpp AbstractHeap.h MinHeap.cpp MinHeap.h
    g++ -std=c++11 -c -g AbstractHeap.cpp
```

EDIT: The problem is fixed! The problem was actually three problems.

1. I removed "virtual" in the declaration of MinHeap. ("class MinHeap : public AbstractHeap")
2. I added "virtual" in front of the destructor in AbstractHeap. ("virtual ~AbstractHeap")
3. I added a compilation rule to create MinHeap.o, like so:

```
Main: AbstractHeap.o Main.o MinHeap.o
    g++ -std=c++11 -g -Wall Main.o AbstractHeap.o MinHeap.o -o Main

Main.o: Main.cpp
    g++ -std=c++11 -c -g Main.cpp

AbstractHeap.o: AbstractHeap.cpp AbstractHeap.h MinHeap.cpp MinHeap.h
    g++ -std=c++11 -c -g MinHeap.cpp
    g++ -std=c++11 -c -g AbstractHeap.cpp
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Also I am rather new to submitting StackOverflow questions, so be nice please :)

Comment: Not going to happen. We are the purest of evil here. Doomed! You are dooomed! Muhuhuhahahahahahahahahahaha!

Comment: See what happens if you change ` ~AbstractHeap();` into `virtual  ~AbstractHeap();`. [You'll want to do it anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors).

Comment: Excellent question - you provided all the information need right from the start.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issues right now, but have the following comments: With polymorphic classes, I would recommend always declaring the destructor virtual, because every derived class might have data members with destructors that might not get destroyed then. Secondly, you probably don't want *virtual inheritance*, since you don't use multiple inheritance, so I would drop the `virtual` before `public AbstractHeap`. Thirdly, I would recommend to use `std::vector` instead of manually handling your memory with `new` and `delete` and finally, your header guard for MinHeap.h seems to be broken.

Comment: BTW [Effective C++ -item 7 declare destructors virtual in polymorphic base classes](https://blog.ycshao.com/2012/03/18/effective-c-item-7-declare-destructors-virtual-in-polymorphic-base-classes/)

Comment: Look at your makefile. Where is the command that will compile `MinHeap.cpp`? (It should look like `g++ -std=c++11 -c -g MinHeap.cpp`.) Now cross-reference with the answers to the question that you somehow thought was all about QT: [Undefined reference to vtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065154/undefined-reference-to-vtable#8923163). *Hmm: quick test: put an obvious syntax error in `MinHeap.cpp`, then rebuild your project. Did the compiler complain?*

Comment: JaMit is entirely correct, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things:

1) This code is very unlikely to be what you want:

```
 class MinHeap : virtual public AbstractHeap
```

virtual derivation is only of use when you are doing multiple inheritance (which you aren't here, from what you've shown), and even then it's best avoided.

You simply need:

```
class MinHeap : public AbstractHeap
```

I suspect this causes the error.

2) If you have a base class, its destructor should be declared as `virtual`, so:

```
virtual ~AbstractHeap();
```

If not, then when you `delete` a derived class object, the derived class destructor may be skipped. So you need a `virtual` destructor in the base class even if it does nothing and has an empty body, because the benefit is in the derived class.

Comment: In the case of an empty destructor body, see if `virtual ~AbstractHeap() = default;` is available to you

Comment: That was the problem, thank you!