# undefined reference to vtable/undefined constructor for derived class during linking

Tags: c++, inheritance, cmake, virtual

so I'm getting this error
`undefined reference to 'Player::Player(World*, Camera*)'`
and occasionally `undefined reference to vtable`, depending on some slight changes. I've looked around and seen posts such as [Undefined reference to vtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065154/undefined-reference-to-vtable) about similar issues, and the answer seems to be to ensure that all virtual functions in the base class are defined or are pure virtual.

As far as I can tell this is the case, I've tried a bunch of different configurations but always get one of the two errors. Code is below:

```
#ifndef PHYSICSOBJECT_H
#define PHYSICSOBJECT_H

#include <glm/glm.hpp>

#include <array>

class PhysicsObject {
  public:
    glm::vec3 d_acc = {0,0,0};
    glm::vec3 d_vel = {0,0,0};
    glm::vec3 d_pos = {0,50,0};

    //An axis aligned bounding box
    std::array<glm::vec3, 8> d_AABB;

    PhysicsObject();
    virtual ~PhysicsObject();
    virtual void physicsUpdate();
    //virtual void setVel(const glm::vec3& vel) = 0;
    //virtual void setPos(const glm::vec3& pos) = 0;

};

#endif
```

```
#include "PhysicsObject.hpp"

PhysicsObject::PhysicsObject(){
}
PhysicsObject::~PhysicsObject(){

}

void PhysicsObject::physicsUpdate(){

}
```

```
#include "PhysicsObject.hpp"

class World;
class Camera;

class Player : public PhysicsObject {
  private:
    World* d_world;
    Camera* d_camera;
    std::mutex d_player_mtx;

  public:
    //Player() = default;
    Player(World* world, Camera* camera);
    ~Player() = default;
    void syncCamera();
    void syncAABB();
    void incX(float x);
    void incY(float y);
    void incZ(float z);
    bool willCollide();

    void physicsUpdate() override;
    void setAcc(const glm::vec3& acc)/*override*/;
    void setPos(const glm::vec3& pos) ;
    //void setVel(const glm::vec3& vel) override;
    void incVel(const glm::vec3& vel)/*override*/;
};
```

edit: attempt at a minimal reproducible example compiled soooo leading me to think theres something funky in my cmake

cmakelist for this folder

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(input)

file(GLOB_RECURSE playercpps CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "*.cpp")
file(GLOB_RECURSE playerhpps CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "*.hpp")

add_library(playerlib STATIC ${playercpps})

install(TARGETS playerlib DESTINATION lib)

install(FILES ${playerhpps} DESTINATION include)
```

top level cmakelist

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(game)

find_package(Freetype REQUIRED)
include_directories(${FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -pedantic --std=c++17 -lstdc++fs -Wno-unused-parameter -g)

add_subdirectory(Managers)
add_subdirectory(Core)
add_subdirectory(Rendering)
add_subdirectory(Input)

add_executable(game main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(game init playerlib managerlib renderinglib)

find_library(GLUT glut)
find_library(OPENGL GL)
find_library(GLEW GLEW)
find_library(MATH m)
find_library(PTHREAD pthread)


target_link_libraries(game ${PTHREAD} ${GLUT} ${OPENGL} ${GLEW} ${MATH} ${FREETYPE_LIBRARIES})

add_definitions(${GCC_FLAGS})

install(TARGETS game DESTINATION bin)
```

also heres some of the nm output for the lib player ends up in

```
00000000000006ba T Player::syncCamera()
000000000000079c T Player::willCollide()
0000000000000868 T Player::physicsUpdate()
00000000000006fa T Player::incX(float)
0000000000000730 T Player::incY(float)
0000000000000766 T Player::incZ(float)
0000000000000a96 T Player::incVel(glm::vec<3, float, (glm::qualifier)0> const&)
0000000000000a3e T Player::setAcc(glm::vec<3, float, (glm::qualifier)0> const&)
0000000000000a62 T Player::setPos(glm::vec<3, float, (glm::qualifier)0> const&)
00000000000000ae T Player::syncAABB()
0000000000000000 T Player::Player(World*, Camera*)
0000000000000000 T Player::Player(World*, Camera*)
0000000000000000 W Player::~Player()
0000000000000000 W Player::~Player()
0000000000000000 W Player::~Player()
0000000000000000 n Player::~Player()
```

Comment: How do you build your project? Are you sure that you include *all* source files when building?

Comment: Indeed, there is no implementation for `Player::Player(World*, Camera*)` in the code shown.

Comment: ah yeah i just didnt include the cpp since its big, the ctor is definitely defined though. I'm building with cmake which im definitely not an expert at but it builds when i remove the virtual functions so it must be linking, one thing i noticed when inspecting the physicsobject.o file with nm is that the constructor and vtable both show as 0000000000, not quite clear what that output means though

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us, and also include the `CMakeLists.txt` file you use.

Comment: *" i just didnt include the cpp since its big"* -- a good start. Next, make the .cpp file not big. Start by simplifying your headers. Trim `PhysicsObject` down to `class PhysicsObject { public:  PhysicsObject();  virtual ~PhysicsObject();  virtual void physicsUpdate(); };` and make whatever code changes that necessitates. Still get the error? If so, keep moving down the chain. I would expect the definition of `Player` in your [mre] to look more like `class Player : public PhysicsObject { public: Player(World* world, Camera* camera);  ~Player() = default; void physicsUpdate() override; };`

Comment: ok so messing around a bit more seems like the error only seems to occur if i declare a player in a different subdirectory/cmakelist directory?

Comment: "the error only seems to occur if i declare a player in a different subdirectory/cmakelist directory?" - It is irrelevant which directory contains a source file. Just make sure that this source file is added to `add_library` call.

Comment: Are there multiple versions of the header file? Also where's the header guard/pragma once for `Player.h`(pp)?

Comment: Is the build process trying to link each subdirectory independently? (It might be better to describe that as "different library" than "different subdirectory".) That could put you in the realm of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)