# How do i solve this"... .so: undefined reference to '..."

Tags: makefile, cmake, shared-libraries, undefined-reference

I have gone through the internet for hours for similar cases to mine but I've tried all solutions and hasn't got my code working. I'm using a library called "vdo_slam" which has been built and can be found in `/usr/local/include/vdo_slam`. In my project's `CMakeList.txt` I can `find_package(vdo_slam REQUIRED)` with no error. The only problem I have is at the end of "catkin_build" I get several of these "undefined reference to ...." as shown below. I have tried several solutions as listed below. All these undefined references are declared and defined inside the "vdo_slam" package. Any help is appreciated.

Known solutions I have tried:

1. I looked for classes and functions mentioned in the errors and see if there are pure virtual destructors as mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065154/undefined-reference-to-vtable) but they are all defined solidly.
2. I have tried to debug with "readelf" command as shown below referring to [this](https://www.uppmax.uu.se/support/faq/software-faq/undefined-reference-when-compiling-program--what-to-do/). But i don't have the "libvdo_slam.so" which actually includes these functions in the error. I suppose i need to have "libvdo_slam.so" when i run this "readelf" command right? How can i add that?

Error message from "catkin_build":

```
/home/tranks/testing_ws/devel/lib/libmy_realtime_vdo_slam.so: undefined reference to `typeinfo for VDO_SLAM::Visualizer2D'
/home/tranks/testing_ws/devel/lib/libmy_realtime_vdo_slam.so: undefined reference to `vtable for VDO_SLAM::Visualizer2D'
/home/tranks/testing_ws/devel/lib/libmy_realtime_vdo_slam.so: undefined referealtime_vdo_slam/CMakeFiles/ros_vdoslam_node.dir/all' failed
make[3]: *** [my_realtime_vdo_slam/CMakeFiles/ros_vdoslam_node.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j12 -l12" failede/tranks/testing_ws/devel/lib/libmy_realtime_vdo_slam.so: undefined reference to `VDO_SLAM::BoundingBox::BoundingBox(double, double, double, double)'
/home/tranks/testing_ws/devel/lib/libmy_realtime_vdo_slam.so: undefined reference to `VDO_SLAM::Scene::Scene()'
/home/tranks/testing_ws/devel/lib/libmy_realtime_vdo_slam.so: undefined reference to `VDO_SLAM::Visualizer2D::spinOnce(std::shared_ptr<VDO_SLAM::Scene>&)'
/home/tranks/testing_ws/devel/lib/libmy_realtime_vdo_slam.so: undefined reference to `VDO_SLAM::Scene::add_scene_object(std::shared_ptr<VDO_SLAM::SceneObject>&)'
/home/tranks/testing_ws/devel/lib/libmy_realtime_vdo_slam.so: undefined reference to `VDO_SLAM::Visualizer2D::Visualizer2D(std::shared_ptr<VDO_SLAM::VisualizerParams>&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
my_realtime_vdo_slam/CMakeFiles/ros_vdoslam_node.dir/build.make:226: recipe for target '/home/tranks/testing_ws/devel/lib/my_realtime_vdo_slam/ros_vdoslam_node' failed
make[3]: *** [/home/tranks/testing_ws/devel/lib/my_realtime_vdo_slam/ros_vdoslam_node] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:6593: recipe for target 'my_realtime_vdo_slam/CMakeFiles/ros_vdoslam_node.dir/all' failed
make[3]: *** [my_realtime_vdo_slam/CMakeFiles/ros_vdoslam_node.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j12 -l12" failed
```

```
$ readelf --dynamic /home/tranks/testing_ws/devel/lib/libmy_realtime_vdo_slam.so

    Dynamic section at offset 0x161608 contains 42 entries:
      Tag        Type                         Name/Value
     0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libimage_transport.so]
     0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libcv_bridge.so]
     0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libopencv_core.so.3.2]
     0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libtf2_ros.so]
     0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libtf2.so]
     0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libroscpp.so]
     0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libroscpp_serialization.so]
     0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [librosconsole.so]
     0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [librostime.so]
     0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libboost_system.so.1.65.1]
     0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
     0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libopencv_highgui.so.3.4]
     0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
     0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
     0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
     0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
     0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
     0x000000000000000e (SONAME)             Library soname: [libmy_realtime_vdo_slam.so]
     0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [/home/tranks/testing_ws/devel/lib:/opt/ros/melodic/lib:/usr/local/lib]
     0x000000000000000c (INIT)               0xd0bd0
     0x000000000000000d (FINI)               0x129494
     0x0000000000000019 (INIT_ARRAY)         0x35f580
     0x000000000000001b (INIT_ARRAYSZ)       56 (bytes)
     0x000000000000001a (FINI_ARRAY)         0x35f5b8
     0x000000000000001c (FINI_ARRAYSZ)       8 (bytes)
     0x000000006ffffef5 (GNU_HASH)           0x1f0
     0x0000000000000005 (STRTAB)             0x2be68
     0x0000000000000006 (SYMTAB)             0xa7d8
     0x000000000000000a (STRSZ)              545696 (bytes)
     0x000000000000000b (SYMENT)             24 (bytes)
     0x0000000000000003 (PLTGOT)             0x362000
     0x0000000000000002 (PLTRELSZ)           90336 (bytes)
     0x0000000000000014 (PLTREL)             RELA
     0x0000000000000017 (JMPREL)             0xbaaf0
     0x0000000000000007 (RELA)               0xb4058
     0x0000000000000008 (RELASZ)             27288 (bytes)
     0x0000000000000009 (RELAENT)            24 (bytes)
     0x000000006ffffffe (VERNEED)            0xb3e98
     0x000000006fffffff (VERNEEDNUM)         6
     0x000000006ffffff0 (VERSYM)             0xb1208
     0x000000006ffffff9 (RELACOUNT)          9
     0x0000000000000000 (NULL)               0x0
```

This is my `CMakeList.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(my_realtime_vdo_slam)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  cv_bridge
  flow_net
  geometry_msgs
  image_transport
  mask_rcnn
  message_generation
  midas_ros
  mono_depth_2
  nav_msgs
  python_service_starter
  roscpp
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
  tf
  tf2
  tf2_geometry_msgs
  tf2_ros
  tf2_sensor_msgs
  vision_msgs
  visualization_msgs
  nodelet
  message_filters
)

find_package(OpenCV)
find_package(vdo_slam REQUIRED)

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
add_message_files(
   FILES
   VdoSlamScene.msg
   VdoSlamMap.msg
   VdoSceneObject.msg
   VdoInput.msg
)

generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES 
    actionlib_msgs 
    geometry_msgs 
    std_msgs 
    sensor_msgs 
    mask_rcnn 
    vision_msgs
)


set(PROJECT_INCLUDE_DIRS
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${vdo_slam_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  )

include_directories(
  ${PROJECT_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)  


catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS ${PROJECT_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME} 
  CATKIN_DEPENDS 
    roscpp
    image_transport 
    python_service_starter 
    std_msgs 
    tf 
    tf2 
    tf2_geometry_msgs 
    tf2_ros 
    tf2_sensor_msgs 
    nav_msgs 
    sensor_msgs 
    geometry_msgs 
    cv_bridge 
    flow_net 
    mask_rcnn 
    mono_depth_2 
    midas_ros 
    message_runtime 
    nodelet
    message_filters
  # DEPENDS system_lib
)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED 
  src/RosVdoSlam.cpp
  src/utils/RosUtils.cpp
  src/visualizer/RosVisualizer.cpp
  src/visualizer/RosAsyncManager.cpp
  src/tracking/HungarianSolver.cpp
  src/tracking/SemanticTracker.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
        ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
        ${OpenCV_LIBS}
        ${vdo_slam_LIBRARIES}
)
#if(catkin_EXPORTED_LIBRARIES)
#  add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}
#         ${catkin_EXPORTED_LIBRARIES}
#         ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
#         ${OpenCV_LIBS}
 #     ${vdo_slam_LIB_DIRS})
# endif()

# target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} SYSTEM PUBLIC
#     ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
#     ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
#     ${vdo_slam_INCLUDE_DIRS}
#     $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
#     $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
# )


add_executable(ros_vdoslam_node 
  src/ros_vdoslam_node.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(ros_vdoslam_node 
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  ${OpenCV_LIBS}
  ${vdo_slam_LIB_DIRS}
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
  )

if(catkin_EXPORTED_LIBRARIES)
  add_dependencies(ros_vdoslam_node
          ${catkin_EXPORTED_LIBRARIES}
          ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
          ${OpenCV_LIBS}
      ${vdo_slam_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

Comment: If you have built and installed **"vdo_slam"** with headers in `/usr/local/include/vdo_slam`, then I would expect to see [`libObjSLAM.so`](https://github.com/halajun/VDO_SLAM) somewhere.

Comment: @AlexCohn I can see libvdo_slam.so in the /usr/local/lib/. Since I also also find_packaged and linked it in the CMakelist.txt, I expected to see libvdo_slam.so in the shared library list when I run `$ readelf <mylibrary.so_file>`, but it wasn't there. So I ran a short if statement in the CMakeList.txt to check with `if(vdo_slam_FOUND)` flag and if found, print some message. It outputs the found message.

Comment: why does your `target_link_libraries` include `${vdo_slam_LIB_DIRS}`, not `${vdo_slam_LIBS}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eureka!
I found a solution although it's not an ideal one. As mentioned in the question, I noticed that `libvdo_slam.so` was not listed as a shared library when running `$ readelf <on_my_library.so>`. So I manually added `-lvdo_slam` in the CMakeList.txt so it looks like:

```
target_link_libraries(ros_vdoslam_node  
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}  
  ${OpenCV_LIBS}    
  ${PROJECT_NAME}  
  -lvdo_slam  
  )  `
```

Moreover, since "**vdo_slam**" also uses a modified "**g2o**" library, the same procedure had to be done in the VDO_SLAM library's CMakeList.txt(which is adding `-lvdo_slam_g2o` in a similar place).

Although it builds successfully now, I still wonder why this happened. From my understanding, `-lvdo_slam` is the same as `${vdo_slam_LIBS}`, and the latter should be valid after using `find_package(vdo_slam REQUIRED)`