# How is creating a new header file in C different from creating a class in Java?

Tags: java, class, oop, object, header-files

I know that Java implements OOP through the concepts of classes and objects. 
However, I recently found out that I can create my own header files in C.  (I'm kinda new to programming)
I realize that those user-defined header files cannot be used as objects (just like we can create objects of a Java class), but is there any other conceptual or logical differences?

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039903/is-programming-against-interfaces-in-java-the-same-concept-as-using-header-files?

Comment: Header files have nothing to do with OOP. OOP is a programming style. Header files are just a collection of some functions/methods that you can use in your code without rewriting them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A header file in C contains:

- Function definitions
- Data type definitions
- Macros

which you import into your C program with the help of a preprocessor directive (#include). But you should not forget that a C program is procedure-oriented and by no means, a C header file is an exception i.e. the content of a header file is procedure-oriented code and lacks all the features of [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

Answer (score 0):

A C header file simply contains different declarations (*e.g. for interfaces*) to be shared over various source files. For a deeper explanation look here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Header-Files.html

In this manner an interface is just a definition of the functionality a implementing class needs to provide. In none of the two worlds, not in java and not in C you can  create objects from interfaces since this does not contain functionality (*yeah I know of default methods :-)*)