# c++ design pattern question. single interface multiple implementations?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you declare an interface in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318064/how-do-you-declare-an-interface-in-c)

Hi,

What's the preferable way to create single interface and multiple implementations in c++?

For example, I'd like to implement kqueue for mac and epoll for linux and share the interface.

Thank you

Comment: I would in this case try to keep the interface in the header general enough so it works with either implementation, and just make two different detail source files and `#ifdef #include` the right one from a third one. This is not as elegant, but it works. The reason why I would go this way is that it is kind of pointless to use a sophisticated pattern that can decide at runtime if it is clear from the beginning that you will only ever use one implementation on a particular platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) is probably what you are looking for.
The [Abstract Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) can help you fill in the right implementation when starting up.