# setting reference c++

Tags: c++, reference, setter

I have a Engine class and i want to set a command. 
This is the header:

```
class GameEngine
{
public:
GameEngine();
~GameEngine();
MoveCommand command;
void SetCommand(ICommand &);
void Start();
};
```

The problem is the `ICommand`. In the main I set the command with

```
engine.SetCommand(cmdRight);
```

where `cmdRight` is a `MoveCommand`. I don't understand what is passed in the `setCommand` function.

Comment: What's the relation between `MoveCommand` and `ICommand`?

Comment: @littleadv: He does not understand inheritance.

Comment: How can i set command. I pass a MoveCommand with setCommand, but I don't know what code is needed in setCommand

Comment: command = cmdRight? Do you have an assignment operator implemented?

Comment: @user571289: You normally just say `theCommand = aCommand` and someone uses it later. `aCommand` would be of type `ICommand`.

Comment: sorry but what do you mean with assignment operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetCommand` takes a reference to an `ICommand` object.  (You can think of references as if they were pointers with different synax for using them, for now).  Assuming `ICommand` is a parent class of `MoveCommand`, you can pass a reference of `MoveCommand` (e.g. `cmdRight`) to `GameEngine::SetCommand()`.  In `SetCommand()` you will have to convert the type of the passed reference to `MoveCommand` in order to be able to assign the value to `command` -- otherwise the actual object might have a type that is another child of `ICommand`.

Try this:

```
void GameEngine::SetCommand(ICommand& cmd) {
  try {
    MoveCommand& mcmd = dynamic_cast<MoveCommand&>(cmd);
    command = mcmd;
  } catch (const std::bad_cast& e) {
    std::cout << "Wrong command passed: move command expected" <<
        " (" << e.what() << ")" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Note: if you do not specifically need a `MoveCommand` in `GameEngine`, you could declare `command` of type `ICommand*` and use the passed-in values via the ICommand interface.  You will have to dynamically allocate and de-allocate the object, though, so if you are not familiar with that topic, try the above code.

Answer (score 1):

`ICommand` could be the base class and `MoveCommand` is a derived class from `ICommand` so it makes it a valid parameter. It is fairly common to do this when you want to have a generic function but do not know which of the derived classes you will be using. This [SO answer explains about inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/318137/195488).