# Implementing an interface in C++

Tags: java, c++, interface

How can I do this in C++

```
interface ActionListener { void actionPerformed(); }
jButton.addActionListener(
    new ActionListener(){ void actionPerformed() { do something } }
);
```

So far I know this,

```
class ActionListener {
  public : 
    virtual ~ActionListener(){}
    virtual void actionPerformed() = 0;
}
```

After this what do I do ... any keywords to do this kind of implemention would also help.

Comment: Is this what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318064/how-do-you-declare-an-interface-in-c

Comment: I read that before but I don't know how to do the above java concept in c++ , i.e create a pointer to the interface and define its method... i've seen this implemented in java in netbeans to simplify readability of code for actionPerformed on buttons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ doesn't really have anonymous classes like you find in Java. The usual thing is just to declare a subclass that inherits from the interface class. The closest you come to Java's anonymous class instance is something like this:

```
class : public ActionListener {
public:
    virtual void actionPerformed() {
        // do something
    }
} listener;
thing.addActionListener( listener );
```

Comment: @JeffreyChen - It is known by various names: nameless class; anonymous class; unnamed class. It's a standard part of C++. Just google those terms to get lots of links. See, for instance, the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3bbz53t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) description.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much else to do in C++. You may want to use [virtual inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance) when you implement, to avoid the diamond inheritance problem in case you eventually use multiple inheritance:

```
class SomeActionListener : virtual public ActionListener{
  public : 
    virtual ~ActionListener();
    virtual void actionPerformed();
}
```

In C++11, you can also use `override` for the method implementation. This checks at compile time in case you inadvertently mistyped the method name or got the cv qualifiers wrong, in which case you wouldn't be overriding:

```
class SomeActionListener : virtual public ActionListener{
  public : 
    virtual ~ActionListener();
    virtual void actionPerformed() override;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"How can I do this in C++?" -- It looks that what you are trying to do is to register a callback in a button. In C++, you do it in a different way: you do not need to provide any abstract class or an interface (in OO sense). Instead your button is likely to provide the following function for registering a callback:

```
void Button::addActionListener(std::function<void()> callback);
```

The type of `callback` is "any function, function pointer, or reference that can be called with zero arguments and returns nothing". Then you register your callback  like this:

```
cppButton.addActionListener( [&]{ do something; } );
// lambda
```

Answer (score 0):

Inherit from `ActionListener`.

C++ supports multiple inheritance. Java does not, so it must rely on interfaces.

Comment: I know this class myClass: public ActionListener { void actionPerformed(){} }; but is there a way not to inherit from ActionListener, like in java myClass would not implement actionListener because i can create an object of ActionListener and redeifne actionPerformed()