# How can I implement internal abstract member classes in c++?

Tags: c++, abstract-class, internal-class

An abstract class has internal virtual functions.
Can an abstract class have internal virtual classes to be implemented later?

I tried the following:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class C1 {
    public:
        class Child {
            int tmp;
            virtual int getint() = 0;
        };
    virtual Child getChild() = 0;
};

class C2: public C1 {
    public:
        class Child {
            int getint()
            {
                return 10;
            }
        } c;
    Child getChild()
    {
        return c;
    }
};

int main() { return 0; }
```

**Child** is an abstract class which will be overrode in derived classes. And I hope the implemented **Child** can be used to define a function.

However, I got an error:

> invalid abstract return type for member function 'virtual C1::Child C1::getChild()'

Can't I implement an internal abstract class in derived classes, just like implementing a virtual function?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with internal classes. You can greatly simplify your example. Here's a [mcve]: `struct foo { virtual stuff() = 0; }; foo make_foo();`.

Comment: You cannot return abstract objects as value. If you do that, how can the client use it as there are missing implementations for `pure virtual` functions?. You can however return pointer to such object. Additionally: in your example `Child` is not abstract. Edit it as someone may not understand your problem.

Comment: @MichałWalenciak Clients call the virtual functions defined in that abstract class.

Comment: @ZehuiLin: I know, but as you have returned 'incomplete' object, how can it work? :)

Comment: The only difference between a class defined inside another class and one that isn't is the scope of their names. You have two unrelated classes; `C1::Child` and `C2::Child`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the present code, `class C1::Child` and `class C2::Child` have no inheritance relationship. Hence they are totally unrelated classes. Even if you relate them with inheritance, then also `getChild()` cannot return `Child` (value). It can return either `Child&` (reference) or `Child*` (pointer) to form a valid `virtual` methods with **covariance**. Refer: [C++ virtual function return type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4665117/514235)

Such errors are easily caught by using `override` specifier available in C++11.

Without knowing the exact context of what you are trying to achieve, the possible code should look like this:

```
class C1 {
  // ... same
  virtual Child& getChild() = 0;
  //      ^^^^^^ reference
};

class C2 : public C1 {
//         ^^^^^^ did you miss this?
public:
  class Child : public C1::Child {
  //                   ^^^^^^^^^ inheritance
    int getint() override { return 10; }
  } c;
  Child& getChild() override { return c; }
};
```

---

Also your below statement seems confusing:

> *"Child is a abstract class, which will be implemented later,"*

Like `virtual` methods, the classes don't have such runtime relationships.
The best meaning of "implementing later" in the context of class is -- implementing it outside the body of the enclosing class, such as:

```
class Outer { public: class Inner; };
// ...
class Outer::Inner { ... };
```

Comment: So virtual functions and abstract class and treated different? I can call a virtual function, but I can not use an abstract class?

Comment: @ZehuiLin, I am unclear about your exact Qn. However, abstract classes are the classes with at least 1 pure `virtual` method inside their body. The `virtual` method is invoked using a base class reference or pointer. If the base class is abstract, then you cannot have its object. I would suggest to put some examples, if it's unclear to you. Refer this for more details on Abstract classes: [Abstract Class vs Interface in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12854778/514235)

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, `Abstract Classes` are used for creating `Interfaces`. Using `Interfaces`, clients demand the required functionality. By defining/implementing `Interfaces`, servers fulfill the client's functionality. `Interface/Abstract Class` are simply blueprint of requirement/agreement between client and server. The classes which implement the `Interface/Abstract Class` or fulfills the functionality requirement can be instantiated. So there can be many implementation of the same `Interface/Abstract Class`. Now in order to access all these different implementation of the same `Interface/Abstract Class` seamlessly at different point of time, we need a generalized way. And this generalized way is via `pointer(*) or reference(&)` to the underlying `Interface\Abstract Class`.

In your code `C1::Child` is an an`Abstract Class or Interface`.

So, `C1::getChild()` can return an implementation of the `Interface/Abstract C1::Child`. But it cannot return an instance of the `Interface/Abstract C1::Child` itself as per above theoretical explanation. And hence the error.
Proper way to declare `C1::getChild()` would be:

- `virtual C1::Child* getChild() = 0;` or
- `virtual C1::Child& getChild() = 0;`

Also, `C1::Child` can be simply seen as a `class` inside `namespace C1`, since `class` is also a kind of `namespace` with some restriction.

Answer (score 0):

From your post you seem to be confusing things. I suggest you get a re-read on abstract classes and try some simple examples yourself.

> Child is a abstract class, which will be implemented later, And I hope
>   the implemented Child can be used to define a function.

A pure virtual method (`virtual int getint() = 0;` in your example) is not meant to be implemented "later". It's meant to be implemented by an override method in a derived class.

E.g. if you have

```
class Child {
   virtual int getint() = 0;
};
```

you cannot do

```
class Child {
   virtual int getint() { return 10; }
};
```

nor

```
int Child::getint() { return 10; }
```

at a later time.

What you can do is:

```
class Derived : public Child
{
   int getint() override { return 10; }
};
```