# How to compile a C++ interface that's in a header file only

Tags: c++, compilation, makefile, header-files

I have a class Event and a subclass ServerEvent, however the Event class is only an interface for ServerEvent to extend/inherit from. When I run make an Event.o isn't generated and I get an error that it doesn't exist.

What's the right way to compile this interface and what to add in the makefile?
Also, the reason I have a protected constructor is so that Event can't be instantiated. I couldn't use a virtual constructor - what is the normal way to go about inheritance?

EDIT: including the makefile, ServerEvent.cpp and compile error now

Event.h

```
#ifndef EVENT_H
#define EVENT_H

#include <string>

#define EVENT_STOP 0
#define EVENT_START 1

class Event {
private:

protected:
    double time;
    std::string label;
    int type; // EVENT_START OR EVENT_STOP
    Event();

public:

};

#endif
```

ServerEvent.h

```
#ifndef SERVEREVENT_H
#define SERVEREVENT_H

#include "Event.h"
#include <vector>
class ServerEvent: public Event {
private:

public: 
    ServerEvent(std::vector<std::string> tokens);

};

#endif
```

ServerEvent.cpp

```
#include "Event.h"
#include "ServerEvent.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>

ServerEvent::ServerEvent(std::vector<std::string> tokens) {
    std::stringstream stream(tokens[0]);
    stream >> time;

}
```

makefile

```
OBJ = correngine.o CSVManager.o CorrelationEngineManager.o ServerEvent.o
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -c -Wall -pedantic
LFLAGS = -Wall -pedantic
EXE =   correngine 

correngine : $(OBJ) 
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(OBJ) -o $(EXE)

correngine.o : correngine.cpp correngine.h CSVManager.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) correngine.cpp

CSVManager.o : CSVManager.cpp CSVManager.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) CSVManager.cpp

CorrelationEngineManager.o : CorrelationEngineManager.cpp CorrelationEngineManager.h Event.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) CorrelationEngineManager.cpp

Event.o : Event.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) Event.h

ServerEvent.o: ServerEvent.cpp ServerEvent.h Event.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) ServerEvent.cpp 

clean : 
    \rm *.o $(EXE)
```

compile error

```
ServerEvent.o: In function `ServerEvent::ServerEvent(std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >)':
ServerEvent.cpp:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `Event::Event()'
ServerEvent.o: In function `ServerEvent::ServerEvent(std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >)':
ServerEvent.cpp:(.text+0xe1): undefined reference to `Event::Event()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [correngine] Error 1
```

Comment: You need `class Event` member functions implemented somewhere anyway. Where is the implementation?

Comment: If you're getting errors, show your makefile.  Show your other .cpp file where you are `#include`ing this one.  Why do you think there should be an Event.o or the like?

Comment: Ok I included my makefile and other files. I guess I don't need a .o but I'm not sure how to compile it.

Answer (score 2):

1. This is a concrete base class, it has data members so it is not an 'interface'. An 'interface' class refers to a class with no data member and all member functions are pure virtual in a sense.
2. You #include the .h in a .cpp file and compile that .cpp file (but I don't see why you are going to do that, you must #include"Event.h" in the ServerEvent .cpp, right?)
3. Usually, to make an interface class inheriable but non-instantiable is to use pure virtual dtor, e.g. virtual ~Event() = 0; However, this doesn't apply to your case due to my point 0. Protected ctor is probably the right way for your case, but I have to say it doesn't look like an elegant (or right) design ...

Comment: There is no such thing as *interface* in C++ in the sense of an abstract class with no data member.

Answer (score 1):

A class with a `protected` or `private` constructor **only** could not be instantiated.

Of course you can compile it *if you write the implementations* (**EDIT:** if you have the header file only there is no such thing as *compiling* a header file), you just cannot get an instance of `Event` because it is *abstract* in the sense that it has got only `protected` or `private` constructor.

To instantiate an instance, write a class derived from `Event` that has a public constructor and *no pure virtual function* whatsoever.

(Why on earth would you like to instantiate an *abstract* class anyway? If you need to instantiate it, don't define it as *abstract*.)

Constructors cannot be virtual because virtual functions are invoked according to a pointer table associated with the classes (including derived ones). When a constructor is invoked, *that* instance is not yet constructed and no virtual function can be invoked. **But constructors of the derived class will call the constructor of its base class implicitly**.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you do not need the constructor. You need a virtual destructor, and any methods you need to implement need to be equal to 0 and virtual.

Look here: [How do you declare an interface in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318064/how-do-you-declare-an-interface-in-c)

Comment: The class ought to have either a public virtual destructor or a protected non-virtual destructor. Herb Sutter calls this pattern NVI (Non-Virtual Interface): http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm