# Avoiding redundant code in a hierarchy of classes

Tags: c++, design-patterns, inheritance

I have a specific case (in C++) where I would like to avoid having the same code repeated all over a set of classes that derive from another set of classes where I can not paste this code into. And solving this issue somehow ends up with the diamond inheritance problem. The following example will explain the situation:

```
template <class T>
class A{
    ...
    virtual List<T>* create_list() = 0;   //Factory method
};

template <class T> 
class B: public A{
    ... // Does NOT implement create_list, as 
    //List is an abstract class and is not implemented
    //at this level of abstraction
};
```

Now, we have a set of classes which derive from either of the above abstract classes.

```
class C: public A{};
class D: public B{};
class E: public B{};
... and so on
```

And we have an implementation for  `List` in the form of `VectorList`

*All* of them **have** to implement `create_list` by returning a `VectorList`. The implementation is the *same* for all of them:

```
VectorList* create_list(){
   return new VectorList;
}
```

The **only** way I can think of, which will not need me to repeat the above line of code in all of `C`,`D` and the other such classes,  is to create a class `X` that implements `A` and make all these perform multiple inheritance. That is,

```
class X: public A{
    VectorList* create_list(){
      return new VectorList;
    }
};
class C: public A, public X;
class D: public B, public X;
```

However, this creates the diamond inheritance problem which would mean the I have to use virtual inheritance. But I understand that it is not a good design.

Is there any other alternative?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [`CRTP`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp). That should do what you need, if just creating a common intermediate base class is not enough.

Comment: If all the classes implement the same, why do you need a virtual function at all? Or at best only override once when needed. You don't *have* to make all virtual functions pure in an abstract base.

Comment: I don't really understand the link. I just went through the pattern you referred to. Could you elaborate that in this context, please?

Comment: @KerrekSB: All of them implement the same thing, yes. But I dont want it to be implemented at the level of abstraction of A or B. That is, I want the `create_list` to be undefined at that level. Whoever implements the classes A and B, has the liberty to implement it however they want it. It so happens that in my choice of implementation, that is, in C and D, I decided to implement it all of them the same way.

Comment: The CRTP is a way to write code which shall be inserted into multiple classes, and allows parameterising it with the target class and additional info as needed.

Comment: @Deduplicator: it'll be nice if you could add an answer elaborating on how it can be used here.

Comment: I can't tell from the level of detail here but you may have an issue with using inheritance where composition would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Use interfaces and composition:

Create an interface for class A (lets call it IA).
Create a default implementation for class A (lets call it implA)

```
class implA: public IA
```

Create an interface for class B (lets call it IB)

```
class IB: public IA
```

Create a default implementation for class B (lets call it implB)

```
class implB: public implA, public IB
```

Implement your create_list method in implA. C, D and E should be:

```
class C: public implA
class D: public implB
class E: public implB
```

For more information on Interfaces in c++ see: [How do you declare an interface in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318064/how-do-you-declare-an-interface-in-c)