# Interface vs class with pure virtual methods

Tags: c++, interface

I wanted to write shell extensions for windows in plain C++, but then I got confused by the keyword interface. In many articles I read that I can create interfaces in C++ by writing classes containing only virtual methods without any code. For example:

```
class IIsThisAnInterface_QuestionMark {
    virtual MyMethod (
        int firstParameter,
        double secondParameter) = 0;
    virtual AnotherMethod (
        wchar_t *firstParameter) = 0;
}
```

But the author of [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/338268/COM-in-C) article defined interfaces by using the `interface` keyword. So my question is: **How to correctly define interfaces in C++?** (Becuase I grew up in C#'s world, I know interfaces as constructs specifying methods for classes that are implementing these interfaces.)

Comment: There's no `interface` keyword in C++. The header included in that example probably defined it as a macro.

Comment: this was the first site in google when i searched for "c++ interface" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318064/how-do-you-declare-an-interface-in-c

Comment: That `interface` keyword is part of Component Object Model (COM). You may wish to add the COM tag and update the question.

Comment: AFAIK the `interface`-stuff is specific to the `COM`-Interface stuff. Do not know whether you need this for shell extensions.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50h7kwtb.aspx there is a microsoft extension that adds a keyword `__interface`.

Comment: 1st: I didn't know that there is no `interface` keyword in C++. And you are right, in the `ObjBase.h` header is following macro defined: `#define interface struct`. 2nd: I believe you can mark this question as duplicate, because I was asking how to correctly define an interface. (I already marked it as a duplicate)

Comment: @Tobias Shell extensions are little programs extending the ability of windows. They have to be written as a COM component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ doesn't strictly provide interfaces in the way that some languages do. The C++ mechanism is to provide a class with one or more pure virtual methods that declare the desired interface. Strictly speaking such a class is just an abstract class, but one could consider calling it an interface that child classes would then implement.