# C++ Polymorphism: from parent class to child

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

In C++ we can convert child class pointer to parent, but is there any way to convert it back: from parent, which was obtained from child, give child class back?

I mean:

```
class Parent
{
    ...
};

class Child : public Parent
{
    ...
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Child* child = new Child();
    Parent* parent = child;
    Child* old_child = parent; // how to do this??
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: `Child* old_child = dynamic_cast<Child*>(parent);`

Comment: Yes. [`static_cast<>` and `dynamic_cast<>`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast) can be used to do this.

Comment: @david.pfx I've bothered marking this as duplicate, so just applied the link as a commentary.

Comment: Needing to do this usually indicates bad design. You should have a virtual function callable from a parent pointer.

Comment: `Child* old_child = child;`

Comment: @NeilKirk In case of the `static_cast<>` variant, I disagree with you. In this case it may be a very consciously made design decision. For most of the cases using `dynamic_cast<>` you may be right. Such designs are usually broken (though have some rare use cases, or have a necessity to work around in maintenance of an already broken design).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It is sometimes necessarily, I did say usually.

Comment: @NeilKirk I tried to clarify a bit more in my answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> *"but is there any way to convert it back: from parent, which was obtained from child, give child class back?"*

Yes, as mentioned in the other answers, there are two ways to do this.

```
Child * old_child = dynamic_cast<Child*>(parent);
```

The result of the [**`dynamic_cast<>`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) can be checked at runtime, thus you can determine if the `parent` object really represents a `Child` instance:

```
if(!old_child) {
     // parent is not a Child instance
}
```

Also note to get this working properly, the classes in question need to have a vtable, that RTTI can actually determine their relation. The simplest form to achieve this, is giving the `Parent` class a virtual destructor function

```
class Parent {
public:
    virtual ~Parent() {}
    // or
    // virtual ~Parent() = default;
    // as suggested for latest standards
};
```

**NOTE:**
If this should apply to a general design decision, I would strongly disregard it. Use [**pure virtual interfaces**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318064/how-do-you-declare-an-interface-in-c) instead, that are guaranteed to be implemented, or not.

---

The second way of [**`static_cast<>`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) can be used in environments, where you well know that `parent` actually is a child. The simplest form of this is the [**CRTP**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), where `Parent` takes the inheriting class as a template parameter

```
template <class Derived>
class Parent {

     void someFunc() {
         static_cast<Derived*>(this)->doSomething();
     }
};

class Child : public Parent<Child> {
public:
    void doSomething();
};
```

The validity of an instatiation of `Parent<>` and `static_cast<>` will be checked at compile time.

**NOTE:**
Another advantage is that you can use an interface for derived that makes use of

- static class members of `Derived`
- `typedef`'s provided by `Derived`
- ... more class traits, that can be checked at compile time

Comment: The result of the dynamic_cast can be ... iff the base class is a true polymorphic type, aka has at least one virtual function or base. Otherwise it degrades to static_cast (It will be strength-reduced to static_cast when provably correct in any case).

Comment: @Deduplicator THX! Better now?

Comment: Yes, +1. BTW: Using `= default;` instead of `{}` for the dtor body might be slightly longer but does not prevent the class from being trivial, with all attendent benefits (though it needs a slightly more modern compiler).

Answer (score 2):

You need to [cast](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/) the object back to child. This is done like this:

```
 Child * old_child = static_cast<Child*>(parent);
```

and

```
 Child * old_child = dynamic_cast<Child*>(parent);
```

Comment: Would you mind to explain a bit more about the differences and actual behavior of these two cast methods.

Answer (score 2):

```
int main() { 
   Parent parent;
   Child child;

   // upcast - implicit type cast allowed
   Parent *pParent = &child; 

   // downcast - explicit type case required 
   Child *pChild = (Child *) &parent;
}
```

You should use the `dynamic_cast` to do this safely:

```
Child *p = dynamic_cast<Child *>(pParent)
```

**EDIT**

With `dynamic_cast` returns a null pointer if the type is not apart of the base class, also casting to a reference throws a `bad_cast` exception. `dynamic_cast` is particularly useful if you do not know what the object type will be.

On the other hand `static_cast`:

```
Child *p = static_cast<Child *>(pParent)
```

This assumes that you want to reverse an explicit conversion and perform no runtime checks. This allows for flexibility but must be used with caution.

The regular downcast shown above:

```
Child *pChild = (Child *) &parent;
```

Is a C-style down cast (like a `static_cast`), which may also cast to a private base class (not sure about, multiple inheritance), while `static_cast` would cause a compile-time error. Things like *numeric* conversions is a good example to use this on.

Comment: updated answer to explain a bit about the safety issues

Answer (score 0):

Above answers are good, conceptually you can think like this,

Your `Car` object which is derived from `Vehicle` class. You can refer `Car` as `Vehicle`, and can convert to `Car` as it originally belonged to `Car`. But it will be a problem if your `Vehicle` object actually representing `Bike` and trying to convert to `Car`. Thats why you need safe casting.

```
class Vehicle
{
    ...
};

class Car : public Vehicle
{
     ...
};

class Bike : public Vehicle
{
     ...
};


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
     Vehicle* vehicle = new Car();
     Car* old_car = dynamic_cast<Car *>(vehicle); 
     if(old_car) {
         // OK Vehicle is Car, use it
     }

     vehicle = new Bike();
     old_car = dynamic_cast<Car *>(vehicle); 
     if(old_car) {
         // No Vehicle isn't Car, this code won't execute
     }

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: In which way this answer adds any value compared to the other answers, besides replacing `Parent`/`Child` with a `Vehicle`/`Car` metaphor?