# why sun microsystem people have seperated the concept of abstract and interface

Tags: java

Why sunmicrosystem have seperated the concept of interface and abstract class even if they have the same functionality.
Since in c++ there were no interface concept, why sun people have introduced the concept of Interface in java.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318064/how-do-you-declare-an-interface-in-c

Comment: If you think they have the "same functionality", I suggest you re-read your textbooks ... They do not have the same functionality. It only seems this way, if you don't think it through.

Comment: *even if they have the same functionality* - correction needed. They don't have the *same functionality*

Comment: they are not same when it comes to versioning and coupling.you can always add a new virtual member to an abstract base class without breaking existing clients. That's not possible with interfaces.

Comment: In c++ a class with  class with only pure virtual methods will be similar to `interface` in Java, You  should also read about diamond problem

Comment: Stupid as this may sound question does not deserve down votes.