# Why Qt provide a class to subclass it?

Tags: c++, qt

In Qt there is a class `QAbstractTableModel`, its an abstract class. Why Qt designers provide an abstract class, and doesn't provide an actual class that can be used for modelling a table. Why the designer made me to subclass the class to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because that class is not used for modelling a table, it's an interface that all classes that model a table must adhere to. Qt has a few concrete models that you can reuse, simply look at the "Inherited by" list in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html) of the base `QAbstractItemModel` class. Some of these derived classes are concrete, namely those whose names don't start with `QAbstract` :)

If you want a generic model, you can use a `QStandardItemModel`.

You'll need to read up about interfaces in C++. An interface implemented using abstract virtual methods is a very common idiom. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/318064/1329652). In C++11 you can have interfaces that [don't use the virtual method idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17299151/1329652), though.

If you ask "why doesn't Qt provide any general-purpose concrete classes that implement that interface", the answer is: because it's an impossible job. Everyone's data source has different implementation details, and Qt can't possibly divine everyone's approach and provide a universal bridge.

The `QAbstractTableModel` exists to let you create an adapter between your own data model and Qt's data model.

Comment: why all the classes that model a table should adhere to that interface ? is there something that is used for the view that adhere to that interface ?

Comment: @andreahmed Because without an interface it's impossible to write a universal view or proxy to display/modify the data.

Answer (score 1):

There is universal model implementation such as  QStandardItemModel, so you can use this for table, tree or list views as you need.