# Declaring an "interface" in C++ and not emmiting its vtable to every translation unit

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface, abstract-class, pure-virtual

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/318137/5214345) answer, the way to declare a class in C++ conceptually analogous to an interface is like this:

```
class IDemo
{
public:
    virtual ~IDemo() {}
    virtual void OverrideMe() = 0;
};
```

But when I do this, I get the warning: `'IDemo' has no out-of-line virtual method definitions; its vtable will be emitted in every translation unit`. Is there a proper way to use such interfaces in a project without polluting every translation unit with those vtables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You already have a non-pure virtual function: the destructor! Just define it in its own translation unit.

```
// IDemo.h

class IDemo
{
public:
    virtual ~IDemo();
    virtual void OverrideMe() = 0;
};
```

```
// IDemo.cpp

IDemo::~IDemo() = default;
```